# How is Wireshark constructing HTTP Flows?

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark

I'm trying to understand how Wireshark knows what request is correlated to a response - "Follow HTTP Flow".
For example, some http packets may be sent with gaps of other tcp packets.
Some have responses that are separated between several tcp packets and Wireshark needs to understand they are correlated.
Does this have to do with SEQ and ACK in TCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this have to do with SEQ and ACK in TCP?

Yes, HTTP/2 and earlier all rely on TCP for keeping track of the packet stream, and TCP uses Seq and Ack numbers for this, along with the 4-tuple of (source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port).

HTTP/2 has additional flow-tracking mechanisms of top of TCP (that HTTP 1.1 and earlier didn't have) because HTTP/2 allows multiple concurrent HTTP transactions within a single TCP stream.

HTTP/3 (the new name for QUIC) is a different story, because it is UDP-based. But I believe it uses a TCP-like Seq/Ack mechanism to keep things straight.